# Showing the same data on every Page. Nodejs MySql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, pagination

**Showing the same data on every Page. Array have lots of data but it's only showing first ten results in every Page**

**Query is working fine its giving the all results but I think problem in Sort or maybe in Order By. I have no idea new to MySql**

```
async function getvehicles(username, params) {
    var result = {};

    var mysqlResult;
    db.beginTransaction();
    const users = await db.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?', [username]);
    if (users.length === 0) {
        result.success = false;
        result.message = "Invalid User ID";
        result.data = [];
        result.range = '0-0';
        db.commit();
        return result;
    }

    let sortBy = "verified";
    let sortOrder = "DESC";
    if (params.sort) {
        const sortArray = JSON.parse(params.sort);
        sortBy = sortArray[0];
        if (['DESC', 'ASC'].includes(sortArray[1])) {
            sortOrder = sortArray[1];
        }
    }
    const page = params.page ? JSON.parse(params.page) : 1;
    const perPage = params.perPage ? JSON.parse(params.perPage) : 10;

    mysqlResult = await db.query(`SELECT * FROM c_vehicles WHERE imageurl IS NOT NULL OR '' AND proofurl IS NOT NULL OR '' ORDER BY ?? ${sortOrder}, id DESC LIMIT ?,?`, [sortBy, ((page - 1) * perPage), perPage]);
    result.data = mysqlResult;

    const mysqlResultCount = await db.query(`SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM c_vehicles WHERE imageurl IS NOT NULL OR '' AND proofurl IS NOT NULL OR ''`);
    if (mysqlResultCount[0].count > 0) {
        const countValue = mysqlResultCount[0].count;
        result.range = `0-${countValue - 1}`;
        result.totalLength = countValue;
    } else {
        result.range = '0-0';
        result.totalLength = 0;
    }

    db.commit();

    result.success = true;
    result.message = "Successfully fetched Vehicles.";
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I'm curious why you are using JSON.parse on a single param?
Also, can you confirm that `page` and `perPage` variables are generated correctly?

Comment: The problem might not even come from MySQL, you said it yourself that it's working fine, right? Identify and define your problem clearly. Why not show us what do you mean by it's "showing the same data on every page". How many pages? How many data for each page? What did it show and what do you expect it to show instead? I guess it's about this query `SELECT * FROM c_vehicles WHERE imageurl ...`, there's no `LIMIT` or `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` so it should return you everything from the MySQL side. Therefore it's probably not MySQL problem.